# Почему функция так работает?

Tags: javascript

```js
function sum(a) {
  const add = function(b) {
    if (b !== undefined) {
      console.log(b); 
      a = a + b;
      return add;
    }
    return a;
  }
  return add;
}

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()) //10
```

Почему sum возвращает 10, если b нигде не передается?
Почему console.log(b) возвращает 2,3,4? Где 1 потрялся?

Comment: Вам в тему про замыкания пожалуй надо. Тогда поймёте откуда эта b

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а причем тут замыкание? если `b` - это параметр

Comment: А что если воспользоваться отладчиком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `sum` возвращает другую функцию, где имя параметра `b`. Первый вызов `sum` с аргументом `(1)` вернёт функцию `add`. Последующие вызовы `(2)`,`(3)`,`(4)` будут уже  этого самого метода. У которого у параметра имя `b` и будет принимать эти самые значения

---

После первого вызова функции `sum` мы получили фактически вот это

```
function add(b) {
    if (b !== undefined) {
      console.log(b); 
      a = a + b;
      return add;
    }

    return a;
}
```

На самом деле даже это не всё. Но пока бОльшее знать не нужно